# converting Time class object to RFC3339 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, iso

[Google Calendar API(v2)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol)'s time-related query is required to be RFC3339-formatted. When I looked up Time class after 'require "time"', I could not see rfc3339 method.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using ActiveRecord, you can use the `to_datetime` method to convert the time to a `DateTime` object.

```
Time.now.to_datetime.rfc3339 #=> "2014-11-06T10:40:54+11:00"
```

See:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html.

Comment: Note for non-rails use, one needs to require activesupport for this.

Answer (score 7):

Does this help? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-rfc3339

```
DateTime.parse('2001-02-03T04:05:06.123456789+07:00').rfc3339(9)
                          #=> "2001-02-03T04:05:06.123456789+07:00"
```

Comment: Aha, DateTime.now.to_s simply gives response in rfc3339 format. Thanks!

Comment: What I wanted to do was to yield next day's 00:00 in RFC3339, and '+' should have been encoded. So that I now ended up with `Date.today.next.to_time.to_datetime.to_s.gsub('+','%2B')`. This looks quite a JavaScript method chain. Hmmm

Answer (score 7):

The way I chose to do this was `Time.now.utc.strftime('%FT%TZ')`
`#=> "2013-08-15T06:13:28Z"` which is perfect for an HTML5 `type='datetime'` input field.

Answer (score 0):

[A website](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2008/11/01/ruby-formatting-time-values-as-rfc3339/) mentioned that RFC3339 is most common date format in RSS feeds, so that the conversion method is implemented as #xmlschema, but not #rfc3339.

Comment: Should this be a comment instead of an answer? :)