# Changing time format to rfc3339 in ruby on rails for google calendar api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, rfc3339

[image]

This snap is from the terminal where it shows the parameters I get from post request, I am creating sessions and then adding them to google calendar, I am not sure how to set up these date and time params in rfc3339 format or any other better-looking format

```
def new_event(sessions_params)
      client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
      client.update!(session[:authorization])

      service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
      service.authorization = client


      @subject = params[:tutor_session][:subject]
      event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
        start: {

       date_time: "2018-04-10T13:00:00-07:00"

     },
     end: {

        date_time: "2018-04-10T15:00:00-07:00"

      },

        summary: @subject,
      })
      result = service.list_calendar_lists.items[0].id

      service.insert_event(result, event)

      end
```

I have hardcoded the time in there right now, but want to add through my sessions
P.S subject works fine

my form:

```
<section class="tutor_session">
<h3>Create new tutor session</h3>


<%= form_with scope: :tutor_session, url:tutor_sessions_path, local: true do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :subject %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<% if @user.role == "Student" %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Tutored by: " %>
    <select name="tutor_session[tutor_id]" class="form-control">
      <% @user.students.find(@user.id).tutors.all.each do |t| %>
        <option value="<%= t.user_id %>"><%= User.find(t.user_id).firstname + " " + User.find(t.user_id).lastname%></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
  </div>

  <% elsif @user.role == "Tutor" %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :"Tutoring: " %>
      <select name="tutor_session[student_id]" class="form-control">
        <% @user.tutors.find(@user.id).students.all.each do |s| %>
          <option value="<%= s.user_id %>" class="name"><%= User.find(s.user_id).firstname + " " + User.find(s.user_id).lastname%></option>
        <% end %>
      </select>
    </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.date_select :date, start_year: Date.current.year, start_month: Date.current.month, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-inline">
    <%= f.label :"Start time" %>
    <%= f.time_select :starttime, {ampm: true}, class: 'form-control' %> </br>
    <%= f.label :"End time" %>
    <%= f.time_select :endtime, {ampm: true}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247288/converting-time-class-object-to-rfc3339-in-ruby

Comment: my question not only to convert to rfc3339, my main issue is to got get parameters such as "tutor_session" => {........., "starttime(2i)" => "4" ....}

Comment: how's yr form look like ?

Comment: @7urkm3n i have inserted the form in the orignal question on the top